# Selecting distinct within a select statment.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi in the following select statement I want to select the distinct values b.bId for one of the column and not working. Statement is

```
select
    a.sId
   ,distinct b.bId  
    from tlocal a
    left outer join ts b on (b.id=a.mainId)
    where 
    a.id=@xId;
```

I have to select the distinct in the select statement since this is returning values in a stored procedure. 
Let me know please, thanks

Comment: Distinct works for the entire record and not only for a specific column. Check @Sparky's answer.

Comment: Some sample data and desired output would help, it's unclear exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  select
        a.sId,b.theId  
        from tlocal a
        left outer join (select distinct b.ID as theID from ts) b 
           on (b.theid=a.mainId)
        where         a.id=@xId;
```

Comment: b.ID is varchar. So when i run this it gives can not convert varchar to int.

Comment: so while doing the join convert it to varchar:  on convert(varchar(10),b.theid)=a.mainId)

Comment: @J.Davidson: ID should be int. Don't make your primary keys, especially ones named "ID" a string type.

Answer (score 0):

Since `a.id` is only one value, you can do distinct to the rows

```
select distinct a.sId, b.bId  
from tlocal a
left outer join ts b on (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(b.id) = 1 THEN convert(int, b.id) ELSE NULL END = a.mainId)
where a.id=@xId;
```

since `b.ID` is `varchar` I'm trying to convert to `int`, since I can't be sure what kind of align  `b.ID` could be, e.g. leading zeroes or spaces, anyway having a FK of different type is bad policy.

1+ to `@siride` comment